# Определение букв в слове. C++

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
По заданию нужно определить, сколько вариантов анаграмм можно составить из букв, содержащихся в слове, которое ввёл пользователь. Букв может быть не более 12. Я это реализовал через strlen и факториал количества букв, сама программа достаточно простая (приложил скрин). Я не учёл того,что в слове могут быть одинаковые буквы,  нужно считать их за одну. Вопрос, как можно определить, есть ли в слове одинаковые буквы и сколько их? Так же компилятор на телефоне считает одну русскую буквы за две, с латинскими же все норм. Хелп, плз.

Comment: *компилятор на телефоне* - месье знает толк...

Comment: ну не на микроволновке же, значит норм.

Comment: Было бы неплохо перейти на `std::string`. В данной задаче можно воспользоваться [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)

Comment: На телефоне - отлично! только писать невозможно, гуглоклава делает свое дело, а так все ничего :)

Comment: А кто память под слово выделять будет?

Comment: Вообще-то количество анаграмм считается не так; ну никак нельзя считать одинаковые буквы за одну. `aaaab` - в вашем варианте только 2 анаграммы, в то время как реально их 5: aaaab, aaaba, aabaa, abaaa, baaaa. Намек: их 5!/(1!*4!)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать очень хитрым путем. Сначала перевести всю строку в нижний регистр, отсортировать массив, удалить повторяющиеся элементы и узнать длину конечной строки.

Пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "abbA";
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower); // Переводим всю строку в нижний регистр
    std::sort(str.begin(),str.end()); // Сортируем
    str.erase(std::unique(str.begin(), str.end()), str.end()); // Убираем повторяющиеся элементы
    std::cout << str.length(); // Выводим количество букв
}
```

Вы можете проверить эту программу здесь: http://cpp.sh/3e4nf

При использовании русских символов в строке программа не работает. Как это исправить пока не представляю.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно так.

```
unordered_set<char> set;
for (auto a:word)
    set.insert(a);
auto numOfUniqueElem=set.size();
```

Вот таким образом получили количество букв без повторов. P.s пишу с телефона так что где то мог ошибится в синтаксисе